# Adding new XML element on an existing xml element

Tags: java, xml

I want to create a new XML doc. I use a method to create the root element of my new xml doc and this method returns me the root element.

Than I create another method to add a child to the root element returned by the first method.

The problem is that when I use this two methods separately I don't get any result, but when I use only one method to do all the job of this two method I get the expected result. 
**This is the code when it works OK:**

```
public static Node setRootElement (Document bpmn_doc){
        Element rootElement = bpmn_doc.createElement("bpmn2:definitions");

        Element processNode = bpmn_doc.createElement("bpmn2:process");

        processNode.setAttribute("id", "Definitions_1"); 
        rootElement.appendChild(processNode);
        System.out.println(rootElement.getNodeName());
        System.out.println(processNode.getAttribute("id"));

        return rootElement;

    }
```

And the result is:

```
bpmn2:definitions
Definitions_1
```

When I use two separate methods to do this job in this way:

```
public static Node setRootElement (Document bpmn_doc){
        Element rootElement = bpmn_doc.createElement("bpmn2:definitions");
        return rootElement;
    }

public static Node appendProcessNode(Document bpmn_doc) {
        Node rootElement = setRootElement(bpmn_doc);
        Element processNode = bpmn_doc.createElement("bpmn2:process");
                processNode.setAttribute("id", "Definitions_1");
        rootElement.appendChild(processNode);
        System.out.println(rootElement.getNodeName());
        System.out.println(processNode.getAttribute("id"));
        return processNode ;
    }
```

I don't get any result.

This is where the method is called:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
appendProcessNode(buildTheDocument());
    }
```

where buildTheDocument() is the method that creates the new xml doc:

```
public static Document buildTheDocument () throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document bpmn_doc = builder.newDocument(); //Krijoj nje document te ri ku do ruaj versionin BPMN
        return bpmn_doc;
    }
```

Any idea how to resolve this please?

Comment: Please show the code that is calling these methods in each cases.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I note you edited it to the request of @AlexanderTokarev, rather than post an MCVE.  I stick by my recommendation.  Make it so that it is easy for people to reproduce the problem by posting a minimal example that runs, along with a short XML file.

Comment: In the second example you declare appendProcessNode method to return a Node, but you actually don't have return statement. Does it compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem !
I keep the two methods I' ve created but with a little difference at the second method. I don't append the processNode I create to the root element inside this method

```
public static Node appendProcessNode(Document bpmn_doc) {
        NodeList processNodes = bpmn_doc.getElementByTagName("bpmn2:process");
        Node processNode = processNode.item(0);
        processNode.setAttribute("id", "Definitions_1");
    }
```

instead I create another method and do the job here:

```
 public static createXml (Document bpmn_doc){
    Node rootElement = setRootElement(bpmn_doc);
    Node processNode = createProcessNode(bpmn_doc);
    rootElement.appendChild(processNode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 programs are not identical! 
In the second example, you have used

```
Node rootElement
```

In the first Example you have used:

```
Element rootElement
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: The Element interface is a subinterface of the Node interface. According to Liskov substitution principle(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) one can say that they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway
I wouldn't proceed like you did with the 2 different methods. Instead try this.

```
public static Node setRootElement (Document bpmn_doc){
        Element rootElement = bpmn_doc.createElement("bpmn2:definitions");
        return rootElement;
    }

public static Node appendProcessNode(Document bpmn_doc) {
        Node rootElement = setRootElement(bpmn_doc);
        NodeList processNodes = bpmn_doc.getElementByTagName("bpmn2:process");
        Node processNode = processNode.item(0);// add more control to make sure the nodelist is not empty
        processNode.setAttribute("id", "Definitions_1");
        rootElement.appendChild(processNode);
        System.out.println(rootElement.getNodeName());
        System.out.println(processNode.getAttribute("id"));
    }
```

I suspect that the Node you get from the first method doesn't have any reference to the actual node withing the document object bpmn2_doc!
I haven't tested the code, but check the javadoc to find out more what are the methods available for the objects Element/Node.